# Is there any way to find the ListIterator.set() source code?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

addAll at index, iterator set methods

Based on the lectures this week, we implemented ArrayList -- an order-dependent collection that grows as more data is added to it. Overall, it was based on an underlying array. However, two methods were left unimplemented: ArrayList.addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E>) and ArrayListIterator.set(E element). In this problem you are to implement those methods. A suite of test cases is provided. Consulting the documentation for List and ListIterator may be helpful.

You should not need access to any private fields, but based on the presentation in class, the following data and methods have been made protected instead of private so that you may access them:

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
    protected static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
    protected E [] data;
    protected int size;
    protected int modCount;

    protected void ensureCapacity(int requiredCapacity) {
        // etc.
    }

    protected class ArrayListIterator implements ListIterator<E> {
        protected int cursor;
        protected int priorCursor;
        protected int expectedModCount;

        protected void checkForComodification() {
            // etc.
        }
        
        protected void updateAndSynchronizeModeCounts() {
            // etc
        }
    }
```

**Here is the program:**

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;

/**
 * Write a description of class W7Problem here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class W7Problem<E> extends ArrayList<E>
{
    // Scaffolding for the problem. Don't touch.
    public W7Problem() {
        super();
    }

    // Scaffolding for the problem. Don't touch.
    public W7Problem(int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts all the elements of <tt>coll</tt> into this collection at
     * the specified location.  If both this collection and the parameter
     * are the same collection, then the operational behavior is undefined
     * (i.e. bad things can happen).
     * @param index the location at which to insert
     * @param coll the collection from which to draw elements for addition.
     * @return true when this collection is modified as a result.
     * 
     * Time complexity: TODO___________
     */
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> coll) {
        // TODO: your code goes here
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        //checkBoundInclusive(index);
        Iterator<? extends E> itr = coll.iterator();
        int csize = coll.size();
    
        modCount++;
        if (csize + size > data.length){
            ensureCapacity(size + csize);
        }
        int end = index + csize;
        if (size > 0 && index != size){
            System.arraycopy(data, index, data, end, size - index);
        }
        size += csize;

        for ( ; index < end; index++){
            data[index] = itr.next();
        }
        return csize > 0;

    }

    // Scaffolding for the problem. Don't touch.
    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return listIterator();
    }

    // Scaffolding for the problem. Don't touch.
    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        return listIterator(0);
    }

    // Scaffolding for the problem. Don't touch.
    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
        return new W7ProblemIterator(index);
    }

    private class W7ProblemIterator extends ArrayList<E>.ArrayListIterator {
        // Scaffolding for the probmem. Don't touch.
        public W7ProblemIterator(int startIndex) {
            super(startIndex);
        }

        /**
         * Replaces the last element returned by either <tt>next</tt> or
         * <tt>previous</tt>.  Cannot be called immediately after <tt>add</tt>
         * or <tt>remove</tt>.
         * @param obj the object with which to replace the one returned
         * earlier.
         * 
         * Time complexity: TODO___________
         */
        @Override
        public void set(E obj) {
            // TODO: Your code goes here
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported");
    }
        
        
    }
}
```

I have completed the addAll() method without any trouble and passed all of the test cases. My problem is with the set() method. No matter what I try, I cannot pass the last 3 test cases.

**Is there any way to find the ListIterator.set() source code?**

Any help is appreciated. I'm looking for a point in the right direction in how to write my set() method.

Thank you!

Comment: ListIterator<E> is an interface which you need to implement. The source code is just "void set(E e);" (see https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/ListIterator.java)

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense now. But how does the method work within the Java.util.ListIterator? Is there a way to look at the internals?

Comment: [OpenJDK 11 ArrayList Source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)